# How to sent a notification to all users using FCM?

Tags: java, android, rest, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am able to sent a custom notification to my own device using Advanced REST Client using this code:

https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

content-type  application/json

Authorization  KEY=XXXXXXXXXX

```
{
"data": {
"title": "Update",
"content": "Test"
},
"to": "cju4nq0nQ9C8YAkVZZ_lh7:APA91bG........
}
```

I have no idea how to send this to all users. I read something about using topics, but don't know how to apply that here.

Can you point me in a direction or have a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

What I did was assign all users to the same topic using this:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("leden")
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    String msg = getString(R.string.msg_subscribed);
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        msg = getString(R.string.msg_subscribe_failed);
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, msg);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Then in the Advanced REST Client (Google Chrome Extention):

```
{ 
    "data": { 
        "title": "Update", 
        "content": "Test"
    },
    "to": "/topics/leden"
}
```